# How can I set up a triple boot with encrypted system partitions and shared /home?

Tags: dual-boot, encryption, shared-folders

I wanted to run 12.04 (32 bit), 12.10 (64 bit) and Windows 7 with full system encryption on either one of the Ubuntu installations and preferably a shared /home partition (at least the data with encryption).

I have no idea how to go about it or for that matter if it's even possible. So now I get to my question: Can you please point me in the right direction or get me started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encryption for both Ubuntu would be easy with ecryptfs (encrypted home folder, on a per user basis). Just make `/home` a separate partition and mount it in both Ubuntu installations. Name the user the same and give them the same password. Click “encrypt home directory” on installation.

An encryption for both Ubuntu and Windows seems harder. The only thing I can think of is TrueCrypt, but that will probably not work as neatly as ecryptfs.

So I would probably say that you install all operating systems with full disk encryption (dm-crypt/LVM for Linux, TrueCrypt, PGP or Bitlocker for Windows). Then you create a data partition which is encrypted with TrueCrypt. When you log in, mount that data partition.

Comment: Thank you queueoverflow. I am relatively new to this. So windows i dont need to encrypt, one problem solved (It would probably mess up the bootloader anyway). So i should then install the 12.04 with /home on a seperate partition, then install 12.10 on a fully encrypted partition with the /home mounted on the same partition as the 12.04. Now if i encrypt the /home partition wont one of the installed ubuntu fail to mount/read it?

Comment: If you install fully encrypted, it will probably to an encrypted LVM in which the other partitions are. You need to make / encrypted but /home not within that encrypted LVM. Then you can encrypt /home on its own with its own key (or with ecryptfs).